# createRef in reactjs is giving error (this.canvas.current is always null)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I want to add a ref to canvas element.
My code is-

```
componentDidMount(){
        const canvas = this.canvas.current
        console.log(canvas)
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        const img = this.memeImage
    }
```

the constructor contains

```
this.canvas = React.createRef()
this.memeImage = React.createRef()
```

And the jsx elements are -

```
<canvas ref={this.canvas} height='400px' width='400px' />
<img ref={this.memeImage} width='300px' src={imageArray[0].url} alt='not found' />
```

The error that i get is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
  28 |    componentDidMount(){
  29 |        const canvas = this.canvas.current
  30 |        console.log(canvas)
> 31 |        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  32 |^        const img = this.memeImage
  33 |    }
  34 |
```

I did `console.log(this.canvas)` it gives - `current: null`
What am i doing wrong here ??

Comment: Refs are assigned before `componentDidMount` is called, so should be accessible there AS LONG AS THEY WERE ACTUALLY RENDERED

Comment: If i remove the componenetDidMount then the canvas gets rendered. But when i add it , it throws error

Answer (score 0):

To add a ref to a canvas element in React, you can use the useRef hook and the ref attribute.

```
 <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="400" height="400" />
```

The useRef hook is used to create a ref called canvasRef. The ref is then passed to the canvas element using the ref attribute.

```
const canvasRef = useRef(null);
```

Once the ref is attached to the canvas element, you can use it to access the canvas element and its properties and methods.
Note that the useRef hook returns a mutable object, which means that you can update the value of the ref directly. For example, you could use the following code to update the value of the canvasRef to refer to a different canvas element.

```
const canvas = canvasRef.current!;

canvas.getContext("2d")
```

Comment: *"Code without an explanation is rarely useful, however. At least provide a sentence or two to explain what’s going on."* - [ANSWERING TECHNICAL QUESTIONS HELPFULLY by Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/)